# What garbage collectors are there available for C++?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

What garbage collectors are there available for C++? Are you using any of them? With what results?

Comment: There is no need for a garbage collector in the general case as the C++ smart pointers are superior and give deterministic destruction. If you a have a particular "Use Case" for garbage collection then maybe we could answer the question more thoughtfully.

Comment: @Martin - your comment looks like an answer.  You should post it so people can properly vote on it.

Comment: Boehm has given a presentation for the ISO C++ committee on GC (2004 IIRC, when smart pointers were well known) so it seems Martins opinion should not be stated as a fact.

Comment: @MSalters: Don't get me wrong. There is a place for GC in C++. But Smart pointers in the general case are preferred. So the need for GC comes down to specialized situations. Therefore to answer the part 'What Result' you need to understand the reason why you need GC.

Comment: Smart pointers don't define any particular semantics (they could be non-deterministic, or not destroy anything ever). A specific implementation such as shared_ptr does define semantics - and they aren't general purpose because they don't handle cyclic references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library includes some shared_ptr stuff that basically acts as a reference counting garbage collector.  If you embrace the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) principle of C++ design, that and auto_ptr will fill your need for a "garbage collector".

Comment: Not if you want to be able to model cyclical references.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: Actually Boost contains weak_ptr as well, to address that.

Comment: @JosephGarvin True - but then you have to pick the right one. With a GC, you don't (which is what the OP asked about).

Answer (score 5):

Several C++ GC are listed [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#External_links).

However, I don't use any, RAII is also my friend.

Answer (score 5):

The Boehm garbage collector is pretty good for C, but tricky to use under C++.  Check the "C++ interface" section at http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/gcinterface.html.

My opinion is that if you need garbage collection, choose a langage that has it built-in.

The best general solution for C++ is shared pointers (from boost for example) with you dealing with circular dependencies.  There are two things you can do:
1. design the thing with no circular dependencies
2. design the thing with a 'linch-pin' that breaks the circle to allow reclamation of the objects

Either you deal with real bad, convoluted, hard to debug problems with a garbage collector for C++ or you deal with the simpler classical problem of freeing your objects when you are done with them.

Answer (score 4):

The only one I've heard of personally is the [Boehm garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) I'm sure others exist, but I've not dealt with them (or looked for them either).

Answer (score 2):

There's always, ahem: [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx?ppud=4) -- C++ for the .NET Framework. Pretty good garbage collection there. :p

Although, to be honest, with all the syntactic sugar they put in there, you could almost consider it a whole new language that just happens to work with C/C++ fairly well.

If you're not married to C++ as a language, you could also look into [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/), which compiles to native code like C++ (and unlike C++/CLI) but also has garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can find several implementations [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/#C++%20/%20MFC%20/%20STL%20-%20Memory%20Management). I have never tried any of them and in general I find a non-deterministic GC causing more harm than good.